# How to use a loop to validate value against static variable and run corresponding functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

How to make the following code block in loops using python 3.6

```
choose = 'apple, orange, mango, banana'
print("select choose: " + choose)
choose_selection = input(" Which one you choose:")
if choose_selection == "apple":
     apple()
elif choose_selection == "orange":
     orange()
elif choose_selection == "mango":
     mango()
elif choose_selection == "banana":
     banana()
else:
    logging.error("\nNot a valid choose!")
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? If you want to put it in a loop, put it in a loop. Are you aware of how loops work in Python? What specific problem did you encounter when trying to put this into a loop?

Answer (score 3):

you can wrap your code in a while loop and then break based on some condition. Also you could put your functions in a dict to save you havint to write multiple if else logic.

```py
def apple():
    print("This is the apple func")

def orange():
    print("this is the orange func")

def mango():
    print("This is the mango func")

def banana():
    print("this is the banana func")


dict_of_funcs = {
    "apple": apple,
    "orange": orange,
    "mango": mango,
    "banana": banana
}

while True:
    func_choice = input("Please choose one of the following functions: " + ",".join(dict_of_funcs) + ", or quit to exit: ").lower()
    if func_choice in dict_of_funcs:
        dict_of_funcs[func_choice]()
    elif func_choice == "quit":
        break
    else:
        print("Thats not a valid function")
print("you have finished choosing")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Please choose one of the following functions: apple,orange,mango,banana, or quit to exit: apple
This is the apple func
Please choose one of the following functions: apple,orange,mango,banana, or quit to exit: mango
This is the mango func
Please choose one of the following functions: apple,orange,mango,banana, or quit to exit: quit
you have finished choosing
```